# Spring transaction configuration in xml

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am trying to configure Spring transaction in my project. I have this configuration in my applicationContext.xml:

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"
        factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
```

POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2 RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2 RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

On running the application, I encountered the following error:

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml]: Bean instantiation via
>   factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect]:
>   Factory method 'aspectOf' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing
>   org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AnnotationTransactionAspect:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.(Z)V

Suggest solution for the above exception.

Comment: You have more Spring jars and they are probably for a different version.

Comment: @ M. Deinum Thanks.. Yes it was dependency issue.